# Strange behavior with var in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, var

I'm getting some very strange behavior in Chrome v57.0.2987.133 using JavaScript:

Here is my code:

```
var firstName = "Bob";
var lastName = "Smith";
var age = 29;

function happyBirthdayLocal(first, last, a) {
    a = a + 1;
    message = "Happy Birthday to " + first + " " + 
                last + " who just turned " + a;
    console.log(message);
}
happyBirthdayLocal(firstName, lastName, age);
```

As expected, because I did not use `var` in front of `message` in the function, `message` acts like a global variable, and I can access `window.message` in the developer console.

However, if I insert a line accessing `message` above the call to the function, like so:

```
var firstName = "Bob";
var lastName = "Smith";
var age = 29;

function happyBirthdayLocal(first, last, a) {
    a = a + 1;
    message = "Happy Birthday to " + first + " " + 
                last + " who just turned " + a;
    console.log(message);
}
console.log(message);
happyBirthdayLocal(firstName, lastName, age);
```

(no other changes!) now, I'm getting an uncaught reference error, and `window.message` is no longer defined.

My sense is that "failing to declare variables will very likely lead to unexpected results" is at play here and it seems Chrome is in an in-between place with regards to defaulting to global vs. local scope for undeclared variables depending on other use in the program? Can anyone confirm this?

I get similar results in Firefox. I've tried searching for specific information regarding what the default behavior is for undeclared variables in both Firefox and Chrome and didn't find anything more enlightening other than to potentially expect strange behavior.

(I'm a bit surprised this hasn't broken a bunch of people's code actually. Or maybe it has. My (mis)use of the variable here--not declaring it--is in the context of teaching about global vs. local scope; I wouldn't on purpose forget to declare a variable (and would lint my code anyway) so this is the first time I've noticed this behavior.)

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: Its simply because you haven't called your function before accessing your message variable...

Comment: Thank you! What a stupid mistake. :-)

Comment: As a side note, implicitly defining global variables would [result in an error anyway if you are using strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Implicit_globals_and_outer_function_scope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Step through it in order.

First, due to hoisting, the variables `firstName`, `lastName`, `age` are declared, and the function `happyBirthdayLocal` is also declared.

Then, `firstName`, `lastName`, `age` are all assigned their values.

Next you call `console.log(message);`. Uh-oh, `message` hasn't been defined yet. That doesn't happen until `happyBirthdayLocal` is actually called for the first time, which would be on the following line.

Due to the error, which is fatal, the function is never called, and `message` remains undefined.

Comment: you beat me to it haha :p

Comment: Oh!!
Of course. I was assuming that the first pass over the code would go ahead and declare message as a global variable, but you're absolutely right!  

Thank you.